# How would you keep secret data secret in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, security, cryptography

Let's say I need to access a web service from an iPhone app.  This web service requires clients to digitally sign HTTP requests in order to prove that the app "knows" a shared secret; a client key.  The request signature is stored in a HTTP header and the request is simply sent over HTTP (not HTTPS).

This key must stay secret at all times yet needs to be used by the iPhone app.

So, how would you securely store this key given that you've always been told to never store anything sensitive on the client side?

The average user (99% of users) will happily just use the application.  There will be somebody (an enemy?) who wants that secret client key so as to do the service or client key owner harm by way of impersonation.  Such a person might jailbreak their phone, get access to the binary, run 'strings' or a hex editor and poke around.  Thus, just storing the key in the source code is a terrible idea.

Another idea is storing the key in code not a string literal but in a NSMutableArray that's created from byte literals.

One can use the Keychain but since an iPhone app never has to supply a password to store things in the Keychain, I'm wary that someone with access to the app's sandbox can and will be able to simply look at or trivially decode items therein.

EDIT - so I read this about the Keychain: "In iPhone OS, an application always has access to its own keychain items and does not have access to any other application’s items. The system generates its own password for the keychain, and stores the key on the device in such a way that it is not accessible to any application."

So perhaps this is the best place to store the key.... If so, how do I ship with the key pre-entered into the app's keychain?  Is that possible?  Else, how could you add the key on first launch without the key being in the source code?  Hmm..

EDIT - Filed bug report # 6584858 at http://bugreport.apple.com

Thanks.

Comment: You could have some sort of authentication on the web-service and then issue a key for that session from the web-service but that would perhaps be too limiting... among other things.

Comment: The best practices solution now is to use iCloud (leveraging CloudKit) to hold keys and secrets. The app requests them on first launch saving them in the KeyChain,  or on every launch and never saving them. I used this technique just fine in an app at my last company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is that as things stand today it's just not possible to keep secrets on the iPhone.  A jailbroken iPhone is just a general-purpose computer that fits in your hand.  There's no trusted platform hardware that you can access.  The user can spoof anything you can imagine using to uniquely identify a given device.  The user can inject code into your process to do things like inspect the keychain.  (Search for MobileSubstrate to see what I mean.)  Sorry, you're screwed.

One ray of light in this situation is in app purchase receipts.  If you sell an item in your app using in app purchase you get a receipt that's crypto signed and can be verified with Apple on demand.  Even though you can't keep the receipt secret it *can* be traced (by Apple, not you) to a specific purchase, which might discourage pirates from sharing them.  You can also throttle access to your server on a per-receipt basis to prevent your server resources from being drained by pirates.

Comment: What's to prevent a pirate spoofing their own receipt?  How can you verify that their is not spoofed without Apple's private key?

Comment: You have to be running a server. When a device requests service you demand their receipt. Your server verifies the recept using a simple web service Apple provides. Pirates can't create receipts that will validate with Apple. This doesn't stop them from *sharing* receipts, but the original buyer can be identified from the receipt which should discourage sharing.

Comment: "There's no trusted platform hardware that you can access." is incorrect, there is a TPM (Trusted Platform Module) equivalent (the same security measures are in place during manufacture) and the keychain uses it. Even on a jailbroken iPhone access to the keys must be via requests to the TPM and there is a guaranteed minimum time per request.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638860/159801 (selfless plug, but it is my most recent method)

Answer (score 9):

The goal is, ultimately, restrict access of the web service to authorized users, right?  Very easy if you control the web service (if you don't -- wrap it in a web service which you do control).

1)  Create a public/private key pair.  The private key goes on the web service server, which is put in a dungeon and guarded by a dragon.  The public key goes on the phone.  If someone is able to read the public key, **this is not a problem**.

2)  Have each copy of the application generate a unique identifier.  How you do this is up to you.  For example, you could build it into the executable on download (is this possible for iPhone apps)?  You could use the phone's GUID, assuming they have a way of calculating one.  You could also redo this per session if you really wanted.

3)  Use the public key to encrypt "My unique identifier is $FOO and I approved this message".  Submit that with every request to the web service.

4)  The web service decrypts each request, bouncing any which don't contain a valid identifier.  You can do as much or as little work as you want here: keep a whitelist/blacklist, monitor usage on a per-identifier basis and investigate suspicious behavior, etc.

5)  Since the unique identifier now never gets sent over the wire, the only way to compromise it is to have physical access to the phone.  **If they have physical access to the phone, you lose control of any data anywhere on the phone**.  Always.  Can't be helped.  That is why we built the system such that compromising one phone never compromises more than one account.

6)  Build business processes to accommodate the need to a) remove access from a user who is abusing it and b) restore access to a user whose phone has been physically compromised (this is going to be very, very infrequent unless the user is the adversary).

Comment: How does the service check if the unique identifier is a valid identifier post-decryption if this identifier is generated on the client? 
This doesn't prove that the client knows any sort of shared secret, just that it can encrypt a random message using the service's public key.  What am I missing?

Comment: Consider Amazon Web Services. You must register to obtain a client key and a secret key. You use the secret key to sign AWS requests and specify the client key in the clear. AWS queries the secret key associated with the client key you specified, signs the request. If signatures match, you're OK.

Comment: Your answer has no way to correlate the client key ("unique identifier" in your answer) with a registered client on the service side.  I need to do that else I could have any random software accessing the service and that's precisely what I'm trying to stop.

Comment: One problem, as I see it, is that in step (3) you're sending the same thing every time.  Try encrypting "My unique identifier is $FOO and the time is $NOW" (where $NOW includes month, day, and year) or maybe "...and the hash of this message is $THIS".  If somebody signs up though their iPhone, you've now got their identifier, which you record.  If going with time-based, you'll want to bounce requests that have the same time; if hash-based, bounce the message if it comes from two different iPhones.

Comment: "If they have physical access to the phone, you lose control of any data anywhere on the phone." But that's exactly the question. The app is downloaded by people who can have control of their phones.

Comment: z800 is right. If client doesn't have a secret key that nobody else knows, there is no way to authenticate the client as the true client. What you describe is the way to encrypt a message that only the server can decrypt, but in authentication the usage of public and private key is swapped between the client and the server.

Comment: This answer is pretty outdated BTW. Modern iOS has a lot better methods for security these days.

Answer (score 4):

[UAObfuscatedString](https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAObfuscatedString) could be a solution to your problem. From the docs:

> When you write code that has a string constant in it, this string is saved in the binary in clear text. A hacker could potentially discover exploits or change the string to affect your app's behavior. UAObfuscatedString only ever stores single characters in the binary, then combines them at runtime to produce your string. It is highly unlikely that these single letters will be discoverable in the binary as they will be interjected at random places in the compiled code. Thus, they appear to be randomized code to anyone trying to extract strings.

Comment: The letter selectors will show up somewhere in the app (I believe), and so a hacker knowing of UAObfuscatedString could tell that an app was using it. Other than that concern, its a really good solution (IMHO). The selected answer in this issue cannot be implemented by many of us.

Answer (score 2):

If you can bear to be iPhone OS 3.0-only, you may want to look at push notifications. I can't go into the specifics, but you can deliver a payload to Apple's servers along with the notification itself. When they accept the alert (or if your app is running), then some part of your code is called and the keychain item is stored. At this point, that is the only route to securely storing a secret on an iPhone that I can think of.

Comment: Push notifications are a) not guaranteed, and b) not encrypted or obfuscated. Any content sent to a device that way is sent in the clear. So not exactly secret.

Comment: What you are saying would be entirely accurate were it not for the fact that the notification sent between Apple and the iPhone is over a secure connection. So it *is* encrypted. Look in the Push Notification Programming Guide...

Comment: Good idea, the only problem is that push notifications can be delayed even by 30 minutes. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and spent a lot of time poking around for an answer. The issue is a chicken and egg one: how to pre-poluate the keychain with data needed by your app.

In any case, I found a technique that at least will make it harder for a jailbreaker to uncover the information - they'll at least have to disassemble your code to find out what you did to mask the info:

[String Obfuscation](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html) (if the link breaks search for "Obfuscate / Encrypt a String (NSString)")

Essentially the string is obfuscated before placed in the app, then you unobfuscate it using code.

Its better than doing nothing.

David

EDIT: I actually used this in an app. I put a base coding string into the info.plist, then did several operations on it in code - rot13, rotate/invert bytes, etc. The final processed string was used to decode the obfuscated string. Now, the three letter agencies could for sure break this - but at a huge cost of many hours decoding the binary.

I was going to say that this is the best technique I've come across, but I just read Kiran's post on **UAObfuscatedString** (different answer), which is a completely different way to obfuscate. It has the benefit of no strings saved anywhere in the app - each letter is turned into a method call. The selectors will show up as strings, so a hacker can quickly tell that your class used that technique though.

Comment: If you use something like github, then you better use git's **clean** and **smudge** commands via some commit-time script like [expandr](https://github.com/gistya/expandr) to clean out the sections of your code from your dev box that handle this aspect. Because once you've committed it to your repository and the code lives in the sky then yeah, all a hacker needs is your github account etc. Enterprise will use private repository servers internally rather than github for anything sensitive, but startups who can't afford this need to get creative.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this similar question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357491/iphone-client-certificate) and my [answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357491/iphone-client-certificate/357546#357546) may be relevant to your case too. In a nutshell, there was some talk of a trusted platform module being present in an iPhone. This would allow your service to trust an iPhone, even in the hands of an attacker. However, it looks like using the keychain is your best bet.

Comment: Yeah, the keychain is the best place however the data must be entered into the keychain after launching the app for the first time.  This means that I'm shipping with insecurely stored secrets.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider/try the Push Notification suggestion, for initially transmitting the secret to the app & keychain?  Or end up finding some other method to achieve this?

Comment: No, I missed the push notification suggestion actually until just now.  How would this work?  Client app sends UDID to my server, I generate a secret, send it to Apple which delivers it as a notification to the client app, and client app reads the secret and stores it in the KeyChain?

That might work fine actually! I'll play with that before year's end.

I still haven't finalized any solution.  This is a part of a much larger side project that's taking me all year so far to complete.

Comment: The keychain isn't secure. A hacker could fire up gdb on a jailbroken phone, attach it to your app's process and then add a breakpoint at the method where the keychain returns the secret value.

Comment: @z8000 Have you manage to use the push notifications. How have you work around the delay?

Comment: Are the keychains on modern iOS devices more secure than back in the day? Or can a hacker still jailbreak a phone and own its keys?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going have my iphone app upload images to Amazon S3. Instead of putting the AWS credentials in the app, I am going to have the app phone home to my server for the URI and headers to use in the S3 upload request. My server will generate the S3 URI, proper signatures, etc. I can then implement a tighter, more specific security model on my app's webservice than AWS offers by itself and not give away my AWS keys to anyone with a jailbroken iphone.

But there still has to be some trust (credentials or otherwise) given to the app, and that trust can be stolen. *All you can ever do is limit the damage done if someone jailbreaks an iphone and steals whatever credentials are in the app.* The more powerful those credentials are, the worst things are. Ways to limit the power of credentials include:

- avoid global credentials. make them per-user/application
- avoid permanent credentials. make them temporary if possible
- avoid global permissions. give them only the permissions they need. for instance, write permissions might be broken down into insert, overwrite, delete, write against resource group A or B, etc, and read could be broken into read named resources, read a list of all existing resources, read resource groups A or B, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds wonky. Would use HTTPS and maybe an encryption package to handle the key.

I think CommonCrypto is available for iPhone.

EDIT: Still sounds wonky. Why would anyone pass a secret key in an HTTP header? Anyone who traces your network traffic (via a logging wifi router, for instance) would see it.

There are well-established security methods for encrypting message traffic...why not use them rather than invent what is basically a trivially flawed system?

EDIT II: Ah, I see. I would go ahead and use the Keychain...I think it is intended for just these kinds of cases. I missed that you were generating the request using the key. Would still use HTTPS if I could though, since that way you don't risk people deducing your keygeneration scheme via inspection of enough signatures.

Comment: HTTPS is not the concern here -- the app is just proving it knows this key; the key is not transmitted over the wire and is thus safe from eavesdroppers.  The concern is storing the key on the client (iPhone app) such that no one or thing can view it other than the app itself.

Comment: re: EDIT.  Read the question again.  I'm not sending the key.  This is standard HMAC but that's not relevant nor what I'm asking about.  I'm asking how to store something secret in an iPhone app.

Comment: re: EDIT II: yeah. But how does one ship with a keychain prepopulated I wonder?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating a key at run time if possible.  This way if the key were to get apprehended during a particular session, once the session ends, the key will be worthless.  They could still apprehend the key from memory if they are smart enough, but it wouldn't matter since the key would become invalid after a period of time.

Comment: I would if I could. The client key is issued by web service provider when clients are registered, and is thus pre-generated.  By "key" I am not referring to a public key or private key but rather just a simple string (think GUID) like 'f67561d3-7ebd-47c5-97f9-9d35943b396d'