# How to securely include secret key/signature in iOS/Cocoa apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, security, ios

*a long time ago I learned that this is a bad idea.  Please don't try what I'm asking below*

I want to include a secret key into an iOS app so that the app can "prove" to a certain server that a request is coming from the app itself and not some other system.  I know that simply hardcoding a secret key into the code itself is very vulnerable as anyone can jailbreak their phone and attach GDB to my app's process to get the key.  Are there any more secure ways of doing this?  Is it possible of sufficiently obfuscate the key as to make this near impossible?

I believe that this is a similar problem to serial number validation.  Unfortunately, that seems to get cracked regularly and easily.  Are there any solutions to this?

All communication with my server will be done with HTTPS so at least sniffing/man in the middle attacks shouldn't be a concern.

Thanks, M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to do that. But as far as I know apple will make sure no other app is spoofing your app's secret. If it's a jailbroken phone, then the user is in a way taking full responsibility, and possible damage should be limited only to the jailbroken phone user's data.

Comment: +1 for "there *is* no way to secure such a thing." If you put the "secret" into the app, then it's no secret. It's like a dog covering up a bone. A little digging will find it ... especially where the grass looks funny.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'schema' not 'secret', small lapsus. Apparently the OP understood anyways :)

Answer (score 20):

I have been wondering about this, too, and several potential solutions come to mind based around the premise that what you want is to get a user/pass secret key into your app's KeyChain (which is quite strongly secured by iOS and the hardware) and pull it for use as-needed:

1. distribute the secret to your app using an app-specific iCloud ubiquity-container. this data should be excluded from backup to the local computer and is purportedly securely transmitted using hardware-level security to only non-jailbroken applications. pro's: it's not in your application at initial distribution, so harder to uncover, iCloud requires a non-jailbroken device, you can update your secret and it will synchronize to all your apps. con's: it's not really in the secure KeyChain, which means that it can likely be sniffed out on the filesystem if iCloud syncs and then the device is jailbroken.
2. deliver the secret to your app as a piece of free app-store-hosted in-app purchase content. when it is delivered (securely by the app-store, only to non-jailbroken devices) to the app, transfer it into the keychain. pro's: it's not in your application at initial distribution, so harder to uncover, app-store requires a non-jailbroken device. con's: harder to change the secret for all of your installs quickly, even a free app-store purchase may require user authentication, which is troublesome UX.

An ideal solution would be if we could somehow bundle secrets (a KeyChain key/value dictionary) right into the app when we submit it for distribution, the app-store would strip these and deliver them securely to the OS for injection into the KeyChain during install, but out-of-band from the normal app bundle sync'd with your desktop machine and iTunes, and they would not appear in the binaries. Barring Apple adding such a feature, I think there is no truly solid solution, though.

- Update Jun'15: Until the **astonishingly** bad flaws in the security of the iOS (and OS X) keychain are resolved (see [Unauthorized Cross-App Resource Access on MAC OS X and iOS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxxXk1d3yyuZOFlsdkNMSGswSGs/view)) you can not use the Keychain to secure anything reasonably. Don't use it.

Comment: This is very helpful, natbro! Are there any updates for iOS 7?

Comment: I haven't found any additional avenues to do this simply in iOS7 (but haven't looked deeply). I did find that using iCloud to distribute this kind of data can be quite awkward on first-run, due to iCloud flakiness. Once you get the value, it's a great solution, but you can't be sure how soon it will get to the device. Really wish Apple would add something to support this.

Comment: what's the approach to storing private key into the iCloud container?

Comment: It might also be worth considering delivering the shared secret via initial silent push notification (ios 8+). Obviously, if the user disables notifications for the app you are out of luck.  WWDC 2014 session: 713 discusses the topic more. I believe silent notifications are accepted by default, but the user can disable notifications in the settings app by disabling Background App Refresh. More here: https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/watch-list-ios-8-opt-in-changes. Obviously would need to ensure delivery some how and provide appropriate visual messaging if the secret data has not arrived yet.

Answer (score 4):

As an update to @natbro's answer, a great solution is now to use [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/). With this method you'd create a record in the public database and each instance of the app would grab it on start up. Since CloudKit is based on iCloud login, it has most, if not all, of the same safeguards that an app-specific iCloud ubiquity-container would have. There are two main differences:

1. CloudKit is more deterministic when it comes to retrieving data. You know secrets/keys will be available when you fetch them from CloudKit.
2. Data from CloudKit isn't synced to the device or cached in the app's container, it's retrieved on-demand and any caching is up to you, the developer (note: I'd suggest caching the keys in the Keychain).

Here's a quick snippet for retrieving a record from CloudKit.

```
import CloudKit

...

let publicCloudKitDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "default") // or whatever you name it

publicCloudKitDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, error) in
    if let secretRecord = record {
        guard let secret = secretRecord["aKey"] as? String else {
            print("Unable to get secret")
            return
        }

        self.secret = secret // or somesuch
    }
}
```

Notes: You'll need to set up CloudKit as [specified in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/index.html) and then create a record that matches what your app is expecting or vice versa (in this case a record with recordName = "default" which contains a field with the key "aKey").

Comment: since I read this post https://nshipster.com/secrets/ , I was searching how can I use cloudkit to save secrets, finally I see your answer and it does working fine , Thank you very much ! , BTW is it possible to do samething but with private database ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the attacker would be in complete control of the client, the only method would be security through obscurity. You can implement a challenge/response model, but you must make it impervious to many other factors (replay attacks, etc).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code) contains one approach to hide a secret key in binary code.

Don't assume that by simply using https you can't have packet sniffing. What if the attacker changed their URLs inside your executable to point to their server? Then they can act as a relay.

A better way would be to provide some identity management inside the app (user picks a username, password is user/machine generated), and use those credentials for your service calls.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Nubis that there is no 100% bulletproof way to do it.

However, this library seems like a pragmatic solution to the problem:

https://github.com/UrbanApps/UAObfuscatedString

It probably won't save you from a highly motivated attacker,
but it won't make their life easy.

Answer (score 0):

An usual answer is implementing "hand-shaking" protocols, where the server sends a "challenge" and the client must provide a valid answer.

This enables a lot more security than a hardcoded answer, but require a smart algorithm (avoiding standard hashes for instance).

Answer (score -2):

If you hardcode the key inside the App, there are more chances to hack it, so it would be better if the App sends a request to the server each time and receives the key from the server.

Comment: The `client_secret` is used to authenticate the client to the server. So, what's to stop a malicious client from requesting the key from the server?